# Providing a dynamic property name to ngStyle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Is it possible to provide a dynamic property name to `ngStyle`?

For example:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ propertyName: '0px'}"></div>
```

The `propertyName` would be defined on the component, and could be `left` or `right` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an entire style object.

```
<div [ngStyle]="myStyle"></div>
```

```js
this.myStyle = {[this.propertyName]: '0px'};
```